# Is there a way to persist chat history in MS Bot Framework Web Chat after a page reload/navigation to another page?

Tags: azure, botframework

I'm trying to persist the conversation a user has had with the bot during page reloads and navigation to other pages on the site the bot is linked to.

Currently these actions close the bot window and restart the conversation entirely, to the point that the bot's welcome message is triggered again.

The bot in question is embedded in the webpage following the instructions from the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

I have read other articles that have used the conversationId to maintain the chat history between page loads, though this was for the DirectLine channel. As well as some other articles that suggested persisting the conversation in a database and passing the messages back into the chat window. Though this seems doesn't seem the best way to go about it.

I attempted to pass conversationId into the iframe but it did not work. Is there a way persist the conversation by passing the conversationId into the iframe?

This is the code for showing the chatbot in an iframe:

`<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/THECHATBOT?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'  style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>`

This is my attempt at passing conversationId as a parameter:

`<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/THECHATBOT?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE&conversationId?=THE_CONVERSATIONID_VALUE'  style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>`

I expect the chat window to be populated with the conversation the user previously had, what I am getting is the conversation resets and no history is maintained.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible when using the iframe implementation. However it is fairly easy to host your custom WebChat yourself, based on [BotFramework-Webchat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). Would you be able to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to do any sort of web chat customization, then I would highly recommend you steer away from using the Web Chat channel `<iframe>` option. It is useful if you need a simple plugin component, but it doesn't offer anywhere near the number of customization options that [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) offers.

If you will consider using the v4 react-based Web Chat offering (referenced in the link above), then the following example will provide you with the functionality you are seeking.

Please note, for simplicity, I'm saving the conversationId in session storage.

Also, I'm generating a token by making an API call against a locally run direct line endpoint. I've included code at the end for doing the same. You *could* pass in your direct line secret against the `directline/tokens/generate` endpoint in the html file, however that is highly discouraged for security reasons.

Lastly, the `watermark` property used in the createDirectLine() method specifies the number of past activities to display (messages, cards, etc.).

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>WebChat</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #webchat {
      height: 100%;
      width: 40%;
    }

    #webchat>* {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it/dist/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/master/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>
    ( async function () {
      let { token, conversationId } = sessionStorage;

      if (!token) {
        const res = await fetch( 'http://localhost:3500/directline/token', { method: 'POST' } );
        const { token: directLineToken } = await res.json();

        sessionStorage['token'] = directLineToken;
        token = directLineToken;
      }

      if (conversationId) {
        const res = await fetch(`https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/${ conversationId }`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${ token }`,
          },
        });

        let { conversationId } = await res.json();
        sessionStorage['conversationId'] = conversationId;
      } 

      const directLine = createDirectLine({
        token,
        webSockets: true,
        watermark: 10
      });

      window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
        directLine: directLine,
      }, document.getElementById( 'webchat' ) );
      document.querySelector( '#webchat > *' ).focus();
    } )().catch( err => console.error( err ) );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for generating the token. I have this appended to the end of my index.js file in my bot. You can also run this as a separate project.

As I run my bot locally, the endpoint becomes available. You should be able to do something similar if you are running a C# bot. The port used here should be the same port referenced in the above `directline/token` call.

The `directLineSecret` is stored and accessed from a .env file.

```js
/**
 * Creates token server
 */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware');

const cors = corsMiddleware({
  origins: ['*']
});

// Create server.
let tokenServer = restify.createServer();
tokenServer.pre(cors.preflight);
tokenServer.use(cors.actual);
tokenServer.use(bodyParser.json({
  extended: false
}));
tokenServer.dl_name = 'DirectLine';
tokenServer.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3500, function() {
  console.log(`\n${ tokenServer.dl_name } listening to ${ tokenServer.url }.`);
});

// Listen for incoming requests.
tokenServer.post('/directline/token', (req, res) => {
  // userId must start with `dl_`
  const userId = (req.body && req.body.id) ? req.body.id : `dl_${ Date.now() + Math.random().toString(36) }`;
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${ process.env.directLineSecret }`
    },
    json: {
      User: {
        Id: userId
      }
    }
  };
  request.post(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode < 300) {
      res.send({
        token: body.token
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500);
      res.send('Call to retrieve token from DirectLine failed');
    }
  });
});
```

Hope of help!

**Re-updated - 8/6/2021**

The script in the HTML above, technically, works though its implementation is not really clear. I've provided this snippet which simplifies the code.

Also, note the first line below: The CDN has since changed slightly. The current stable version pulls from `latest`, not `master`.

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
  ( async function () {
    let { token, conversation_Id } = sessionStorage;

    if ( !token ) {
      const res = await fetch( 'http://localhost:3500/directline/conversations', { method: 'POST' } );
      const { token: directLineToken, conversationId } = await res.json();

      sessionStorage[ 'token' ] = directLineToken;
      sessionStorage[ 'conversation_Id' ] = conversationId
      token = directLineToken;
    }

    const directLine = createDirectLine( {
      token
    } );

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
      directLine: directLine,
    }, document.getElementById( 'webchat' ) );
    document.querySelector( '#webchat > *' ).focus();
  } )().catch( err => console.error( err ) );
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You're definitely right, this does seem the way to go. I just got the bare bones of it working with maintaining the conversation, now time for the pesky formatting.

Comment: Hi I know this is post is not fresh and new, but it is helping me a lot. Are you sure the above code is correct. It seems the conversationId is only stored when it is already known in storage. So how does it get stored the first time around? Thanks.

Comment: @StevenKanberg can you explain why at first you get the token & conversationId and then you do another call to get the conversationId? Also I don't see how that second call could work like this. It GETs `https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/${ conversation_Id }`, but conversation_Id here is always null as checked in the line above `if ( !conversation_Id ) {`

Comment: I also don't see how this could work. `conversationId` is only fetched and put into sessionStorage. Where are you using it? 

And when I try this the fetch `...directline/conversations/${ conversation_Id }` fails with "Security token not valid for this conversation"

Comment: @Martijn, thank you for pointing out the deficiencies in the update I had provided. I'm not sure how that got so muddled. I have re-updated the original edit making it simpler. I did leave 'conversationId' in the code, for reference, as some prefer to check against its existence vs. the token. It is also used in some other API calls.

Comment: @mplwork, please see my new update that simplifies (and cleans up!) the code.