# When the browser reloads, all the conversation gets wiped out.I need to start over old conversation in bot framework node js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot

I want the browser reloading to start over old conversation

How to achieve this using bot framework node js ?

SERVER : 
running AZURE BOT NODE JS TECHNOLOGY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively easy to accomplish. If you check out this other Stack Overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56969008/is-there-a-way-to-persist-chat-history-in-ms-bot-framework-web-chat-after-a-page/56978924#56978924) you can find information regarding setting this up.

Please note that conversations and conversationIds are only stored on the Bot Framework servers for up to 24 hours, after which they will be removed. Additionally, direct line tokens expire after 30 mins. You will need to do a token refresh prior to the expiration in order to continue the conversation.

Hope of help!