# Detect disconnect Microsoft webchat (Backend botframework)

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

Is there a way for the backend to detect the webchat disconnected (ie, user closed page, navigated away, browser quited)?

There seems to be no out-of-the-box event for it. We rolled our own event (`store.dispatch({...})`) and attached it to the `beforeunload` event, but since it sends a webrequest, thats not supported.

I was thinking about using `navigator.sendBeacon`, but that will end up with a lot of unwanted events since that should be used on `onVisibilityChanged` (thus, webchat can still be active, but on a hidden tab). It seems to me that more people would want to know if the enduser is still active.

Using Botframework

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59978048/how-to-check-if-the-user-has-the-webchat-window-open

Comment: Thanks, but like i wrote, window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  const eventSendActivity = new Event( 'sendEventActivity' );
  eventSendActivity.data = 'User left conversation';
  window.dispatchEvent( eventSendActivity );
} is not supported for major browsers, as it does a http call, which is not allowed in beforeunload.