# Need a way to keep websocket open for webchat

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

Scenario:
Open bot try a few commands.
Close laptop. 
open again.
Bot says unable to connect.

I figured that this is because web socket closed. Is there a  way to keep it open?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to web sockets, per se, but to Direct Line and the general nature of web pages.

When you open a web page it is largely static, assuming it's an every day run-of-the-mill page. If you close your laptop and reopen it nothing about the page should really change because there is no "live" connection being maintained.

However, when you load a page hosting a bot using Web Chat a live connection is opened via Direct Line. If you close your laptop and reopen it, then that connection is severed. Without direction, Web Chat doesn't know how to (re-)establish the connection without the page being reloaded.

Look over the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56978924/3962636). It shows how you can setup Web Chat to persist conversations with a bot when a user refreshes a page and/or navigates away and returns. It *does* rely on `sessionStorage()` for part of its implementation which means it will only persist for the current session. If the user fully closes and opens the window, then a new connection is created.

To maintain "sessions" even when the user closes the window would require a more robust solution.

Hope of help!