# Bot framework composer save conversational data to external DB

Tags: botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer, conversational-ui, conversational-ai

I am new to Bot framework composer.

One of my requirements is to save entire conversation transcript.

I explored some websites and found a possible solution to blob storage/ cosmoDB.

Is that possible to save to external DB (relational) through custom actions/HTTP calls?

Thank you

Comment: refer to https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/5534#issuecomment-763088059, https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/5794#issuecomment-780933578 & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-send-http-request?tabs=v2x

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ranusharao.
is there any hint to retrieve conversation data on scope (turn / dialog / this / user)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

i looked up somewhere similar

[How to display saved Bot Transcripts on the bot? How to retrieve the right transcript for user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64553794/how-to-display-saved-bot-transcripts-on-the-bot-how-to-retrieve-the-right-trans)

hope it helps for someone who stuck for the same thing

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).